# Closure compiler: How to declare object and all of its properties as extern?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I'm trying to compile my Google Chrome extension which makes use `chrome.i18n.getMessage()` and a couple of other `chrome` properties.

I'm compiling using the Java library and have a `externs.js` file that I am including with the `--externs` parameters

I'm wondering whether or not it's possible to declare `chrome` as an extern, without having to specify all the properties I want to preserver?

I've tried the following 3 approaches so far:

**Example 1:**

```
/** @const */
var chrome = {}; // chrome.i18n.getMessage() gets renamed to chrome.a.b()
```

**Example 2:**

```
/** @const */
window.chrome = {}; // chrome.i18n.getMessage() gets renamed to chrome.a.b()
```

**Example 3:**

```
/* chrome.i18n.getMessage() is preserved, but chrome.runtime.connect() is renamed
 * to chrome.b.c()
 */
var chrome = {
  i18n: {
    getMessage: function(){}
  }
};
```

Comment: Why do you redefine `chrome` 3 times

Comment: It's 3 different examples - I'll update my question to clarify that.

Comment: you can use array notation. chrome['i18n']['...']. best practise is to create an externs file however

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with the third example while fixing bugs introduced after compiling and eventually ran into some difficulties while defining more and more properties of `chrome`. My thought then was to see if someone else created an extern file for `chrome` which lead me to Googles source for the Closure Compiler. Google has been nice enough to create externs files for several well known libraries:

https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/#git%2Fexterns
https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/#git%2Fcontrib%2Fexterns

Closure Compiler Externs Extractor might also be useful, if your library is not listed above:
http://www.dotnetwise.com/Code/Externs/index.html

Looking through `contrib/externs/chrome_extensions.js` the answer to my question seems to be: **You can't**.

Looks like everything (or at least the parts you are calling into) need to be explicitly defined in the externs file, to be certain no renaming is performed.